# Write parts from filename including the first line in merged txt / csv -file with powershell

Tags: powershell, csv, merge, filenames

I'm currently working on a PowerShell script that reads out the default printer on several workstations and write the information in a textfile to a network drive.  My last question regarding some text replacements inside the script was successfully solved. But now I work on the second part.

```
Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Printer -Filter "Default = $true" | % {
  $_.Name -replace '(?:.*)\\NDPS-([^\.]+)(?:.*)', 'PS-$1'
} | Out-File -FilePath "H:\daten\printer\$($env:COMPUTERNAME)_defaultprinter.txt"
Get-WmiObject Win32_Printer -Filter "Default = $true" `
  | Select-Object -expandProperty Name `
  | Out-File -FilePath "P:\batch\migration\Printer\$($env:COMPUTERNAME)_$($env:USERNAME)_defaultprinter.txt"
```

The last line of the provided code writes the default printer to the network drive. Now I have there nearly 1500 single txt-files. For better analysis I use the following PowerShell script to merge all the single txt files to one big file.

```
Get-ChildItem -path \\samplepath\prgs\prgs\batch\migration\Printer -recurse | ? {
  ! $_.PSIsContainer
} | ? {
  ($_.name).contains(".txt")
} | % {
  Out-File -filepath \\samplepath\prgs\prgs\batch\migration\Printer\gesamt_printer.txt -inputobject (get-content $_.fullname) -Append
}
```

I receive a file wich contains the default printer information from every txt-file but I need the `$($env:USERNAME)`-part from the filename as a separate value in addition to the printer information in on line to use the data in Excel. Can someone please provide me a tip how to insert the part from filename in the merged file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could extract the username part from the file name like this:

```
$_.Name -match '^.*?_(.*)_.*?\.txt$'
$username = $matches[1]
```

The group in the regular expression (accsisible via `$matches[1]`) contains the text between the first and the last underscore in the filename.

You could use it like this:

```
$root    = "\\samplepath\prgs\prgs\batch\migration\Printer"
$outfile = "$root\gesamt_printer.txt"

Get-ChildItem $root -Recurse | ? {
  -not $_.PSIsContainer -and $_.Extension -eq ".txt"
} | % {
  $_.Name -match '^.*?_(.*)_.*?\.txt$'
  $username = $matches[1]
  $content  = Get-Content $_.FullName
  "{0},{1}" -f ($content, $username) | Out-File $outfile -Append
}
```

You could also directly create a CSV:

```
$root    = "\\samplepath\prgs\prgs\batch\migration\Printer"
$outfile = "$root\gesamt_printer.txt"

$getPrinter = { Get-Content $_.FullName }
$getUser    = { $_.Name -match '^.*?_(.*)_.*?\.txt$' | Out-Null; $matches[1] }

Get-ChildItem $root -Recurse `
  | ? { -not $_.PSIsContainer -and $_.Extension -eq ".txt" } `
  | select @{n="Username";e=$getUser},@{n="Printer";e=$getPrinter} `
  | Export-Csv $outfile -NoTypeInformation
```

Note that these code sample don't contain any checks to exclude file names that don't have at least two underscores in them.

Comment: Hello Ansgar Wiechers, thank you for the solution you´ve provided. But I´m not sure how to use your advice inside the second code in my inital question. If i add it at the the end of the above code I receive zero-array index error.

Comment: Thank you for additional csv-solution. I´m totally powershell newbie but i learn more and more from the professionals on this board here.